# Firefox 3.0 CSS Drop Shadows

Tags: css, firefox, gecko

What is a technique to add drop-shadows to text that would work in Firefox 3.0?

FF3.5 and Chrome support the CSS3 property drop-shadow:

```
p { text-shadow: #000 2px 5px; }
```

IE6, 7, 8 support filters:

```
p { filter: shadow(color=#123456, strength=2); }
```

How would you do it for Firefox 3.0? It uses the Gecko rendering engine and none of these techniques work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid there are no solutions to make that work in Firefox 3.0

Just FYI, ccording to this: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_firefox.asp Firefox 3.0 tends to disappear quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
p { -moz-text-shadow: #000 2px 5px; }
```

But I'm not sure if it was ever part of FF before it was implemented correctly IYSWIM?

Comment: Shame. Tried finding the spec list but couldn't find it quick enough.